# Rendering rectilinear grids in Paraview 5 with flat interpolation

Tags: 3d, interpolation, paraview

I would like visualise a rectilinear grid *.vtk file that I have generated in Paraview 5.4.0. The file contains values of a continuous variable arranged in a regular grid that I want to render without interpolation of the values between nodes.

I can already do what I want to do in Paraview 4.3.1 where I turn off interpolation of the scalar values and then change the *Lighting  > Interpolation* setting from *Gourard* to *Flat* (see image below), so I get a blocky visualisation of the scalar values.

[image: Paraview 4])

However, when I try to do the same thing in the latest version of Paraview 5.4.0 The *Lighting > Interpolation* drop-down does not seem to render when I change it to *flat*, and the surface remains 'blurred' (see below).

[image: Paraview 5])

The program is set to auto-apply changes so I don't think that is the issue. I am quite new to Paraview so I'm guessing there is some secret setting that I don't understand, rather that a bug in the program.

I have included a sample *.vtk file [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8QHyVYdjCzqMVVNYTh3X2ZUcm8/view?usp=sharing).

Comment: The data "type" seems to be PointData, right? I don't think there is a correct way to represent this data on a volume. Unless you do some kind of partition (e.g. Voronoi), you have to interpolate.

Comment: That may well be an issue, but I don't know if that is relevant to this particular problem because I can achieve what I want in Paraview 4, but not Paraview 5.

Comment: What if you use the PointDataToCellData filter? Do you get the desired result in v5?

Comment: A good idea. I tried this but it does not solve my issue - Paraview still performs an interpolation so I still get intermediate values. Maybe I will try to save the data as CellData...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this question was really an [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378) - my main goal was to visualise numpy arrays as grid cells in ParaView.

I was able to solve my problem by importing the numpy arrays to VTK format (*.vtr) using the [PyEVTK package](https://bitbucket.org/somada141/pyevtk) and [a helpful tutorial](https://pyscience.wordpress.com/2014/09/06/numpy-to-vtk-converting-your-numpy-arrays-to-vtk-arrays-and-files/).